# Invalid syntax when using the cursor.execute in python ( sagemaker notebook)

Tags: python, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sagemaker

select *
FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING
where REQUESTED_SERVICE = '["dsp"]'
and longitude is not null ;

1. The above query works fine when i query this in snowflake while using this query in sagemaker notebook/ jupyter notebook it just fails stating **invalid syntax**
2. important point here is REQUESTED_SERVICE = '["dsp"]' , the value is enclosed in single quote
3. this is how i'am using it , but i get a synatax error

```
    try:
        cs.execute("select * FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where REQUESTED_SERVICE = '["dsp"]' and storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null ")
        prev = time() 
        for df in cs.fetch_pandas_batches():
            print(time() - prev)
            print(df.shape)
            temp_all_dfs.append(df)
            prev = time()
    finally:
        cs.close()

    ctx.close()
```

Comment: snippets are unfortunately for JS / HTML / CSS Only .  Please exclude screenshots of text.  IF you feel the text is relevant, make sure it's in the text of your problem.

Comment: Your string is using `"` but you also contains it. You need to escape them `"select ... = '[\"dsp\"]' ... not null"` or use triple quoted strings `"""select ... = '["dsp"]' ... not null"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
cs.execute("select * FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where REQUESTED_SERVICE = '["dsp"]' and storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null ")
```

You delineate the query text in double quoted strings.  Any double quote within double quoted strings must be escaped.

```
cs.execute("select * FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where REQUESTED_SERVICE = '[\"dsp\"]' and storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null ")
```

A more elegant solution might be to remove the literal value from the query altogether and [use a parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#label-python-connector-binding-data) instead

```py
cs.execute(
  "select * FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where REQUESTED_SERVICE = %s and storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null ",
  '["dsp"]',
)
```